# #1064 - SQL join 2 table issue

Tags: mysql, join, sql-like

I am not familiar with using sql. May I know what the problem with this query? The code is as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `products` 
JOIN 'cats' ON products.`cat_id` = cats.'id'
WHERE products.pro_name LIKE 'cats.name';
```

Comment: what is your desired output

Comment: join 2 table which is [cats & products], then search it by using cat_name

Comment: Please include some sample data.  It is not clear what your join logic should be here.

Comment: Cats is a string. Next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
JOIN cats 
ON products.cat_id = cats.id 
WHERE products.pro_name LIKE '%'+cats.name+'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM products prod,cats cat ON 
products.cat_id = cat.id where products.pro_name LIKE '%'+cat.name
```